# What is the purpose of the __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, distutils

When creating a Python package, I am told to create a blank file called **init**.py. What I don't understand is why I need to create this file. The `distutils` build script doesn't modify it, so five builds later it's still blank. What is it's purpose?

Comment: You really should at least look at the tutorial when you don't understand something. It's there for a reason.

Comment: @abarnert - The tutorial I was using (http://guide.python-distribute.org/quickstart.html) didn't mention what it was for, just to create it.

Comment: That tutorial is for setting up your packages to be shared with other people. It more or less assumes that you already understand how packages work on a basic level.

Comment: A cause for misunderstanding here is “package”: a Python package is a directory that can be imported as a module and contains other modules; this is related to imports, not to packaging.

Comment: @ÉricAraujo: It's a little confusing to novices that the same term is used for "directory that can be imported as a module" and for "thing you install from, e.g., PyPI, which may be a module, a package, or more than one of the above".

Comment: We’re well aware of the confusing, and there is no magic solution :(

Comment: And if you want a quick laugh and to see this problem in action, read this chat log: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/conversation/nathan2055-packaging-noob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It a signal to Python that the folder is a package, not just a folder. 
It also contains initialization code that is run when the package is `import`ed into a script.

See [the docs on the subject](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) for more. The most relevant extract:

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the
>   directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent
>   directories with a common name, such as `string`, from unintentionally
>   hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In
>   the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can
>   also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__`
>   variable, described later.